# populate a list or array in different dropdowns without showing the values populated in the frontend

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, data-structures

I have a array with values 1,2,3,4.
I can create multiple dropdown using a add function.
For the first time let suppose the default value of the first dropdown is always one.
We press add and populate the second dropdown the values which are 2,3,4, which should be displayed
As soon as we select 2 as value of the second dropdown, the options in the first dropdown should stop showing 2 as a value option.
Similarly if a value 3 selected in the third dropdown then it should not appear as an option in dropdown 1 and 2. This code works if for every next dropdown but does not work upwards like it works for second dropdown.

```
    $scope.populateDropdown = function(object,loopIndex){
        $scope.dropdownOptionsWithoutSelected[loopIndex+1] = {};
        $scope.dropdownOptionsWithoutSelected[loopIndex+1].options = [];
        $scope.dropdownOptionsWithoutSelected[loopIndex].selected = object.keywordsearchonvalue; // current selected value
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.searchOptionsWithoutSelected[loopIndex].options.length;i++)
            if($scope.dropdownOptionsWithoutSelected[loopIndex].options[i].id != object.keywordsearchonvalue)
                $scope.dropdownOptionsWithoutSelected[loopIndex+1].options.push($scope.dropdownOptionsWithoutSelected[loopIndex].options[i]);
    };
```

Comment: What happens if you select 1 in the third dropdown?

Comment: the number is not important, u can select 1 or 2 or 3 in any of the dropdowns, the only thing I want it to do is that if I select 2 in the second dropdown and this function is called , it should remove two from the array in the first dropdown list  as it removes 1 from second dropdown when selected in the first dropdown.

Comment: So if you select something in any of the dropdowns, it removes it from all of the others?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, this code works for every next dropdown not for the previous ones

Comment: This code works for that scenario as the background of all this population is a JSON. if we select 3 in the first dropdown after selecting 1 for the first time, the code will allow 1 to appear in the second dropdown .

Comment: everytime a change is done this function is called . data-ng-change call this function.

Comment: your solution need to work even for N dropdown or is bounded to 3 or so
you could seperate your model in case is for a static amount of dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky to achieve as you have to create different array for different drop-down. I don't think it is possible to use the same array to update the remaining dropdown list. I tried to recreate the issue. Maybe you can use this as a starting point. Goodluck!

```
 <select type="text" ng-disabled="!item.editable" class="form-control" style="width:25%; float:left;" ng-model="item.val" ng-change="modifyList(item.val, $index)">
        <option ng-repeat="lookup in values[$index]" ng-value="lookup.Value" ng-disabled="lookup.disable == true">
          {{lookup.Value}}
        </option>
      </select>
```

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/zdyryk10/2/)

Comment: the editable thing is he problem, this is kind of working in my code!

Comment: I want the first or second dropdown also to be editable and show the rest of the value which are not selected!

Comment: $scope.dropdownOptionsWithoutSelected this is the second aray the way you used it. actual array is passed in my code!

Comment: Then remove the `ng-disabled` from your select.